# How to import parameters from post method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I get the get method called aidx parameter by post method?
 When I start with the current code, it says that it is not defined. 
aidx is the primary key, and I want to assign that primary key to the Family column.

```
<div id="blogpost" class="inner-content">

<form id="formdata"action="@Url.Action("Detail", "Board")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <section class="inner-section">
        <div class="main_blog text-center roomy-100">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="head_title text-center">
                    <h2>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Article.Title)</h2>
                       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Article.ArticleIDX)
                    <div class="separator_auto"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:6%;">
                            <p>
                                <label>분　류  : </label>
                                @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Article.Category)
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:5%;">
                            <p>
                                <label>작성자  : </label>
                                @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Article.Members.Name)
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-left:10.6%;">
                            <p>
                                <label>작성일  : </label>
                                @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Article.ModifyDate)
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                            <label style="font-size:x-large;">문의내용</label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Article.Contents)
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dividewhite2"></div>
                <p>
                    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
                    {
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-lgr-str" onclick="btnEdit()">수정하기</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-lgr-str" onclick="btnReply()">답글달기</button>
                    }
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-lgr-str" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);">목록이동</button>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />

                </p>
                <div>
                    @Html.Partial("_Comment", new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", Model.Article.ArticleIDX } })
                    @Html.Partial("_CommentView", new ViewDataDictionary { { "CommentIDX", ViewBag.CommentIDX }, { "idx", Model.Article.ArticleIDX } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dividewhite8"></div>
    </section>
</form>
```

```
<script >
function btnEdit() {

    if (@User.Identity.Name.Equals(Model.Article.Members.ID).ToString().ToLower() == true)
    {
        location.replace("/Board/Edit?aidx=@Model.Article.ArticleIDX");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("권한이 없습니다.");
    }
}

function btnReply() {
    location.replace("ReplyCreate?aidx=@Model.Article.ArticleIDX");
}
```

```
    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ReplyCreate(int aidx)
        {
        Articles articleReply = new Articles();
        return View(articleReply);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReplyCreate(Articles replyArticles, int aidx)
    {
        try
        {
            replyArticles.Family = aidx;
            replyArticles.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;
            replyArticles.ModifyMemberID = User.Identity.Name;

            db.Articles.Add(replyArticles);
            db.SaveChanges();

            ViewBag.Result = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Result = "FAIL";
        }
        return View(replyArticles);
    }
```

Comment: You're not submitting anything, you're redirecting the page. You don't need a form for that, and probably a simple link is better than the button, so you don't need JavaScript either. And finally, your security is really bad, you're hiding the button if not authenticated, but everybody can see the JavaScript code and copy & run the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problem in your HTML and JavaScript:

1. You're not submitting anything, you're redirecting the page in JavaScript.
2. You're hiding the button if the user is not authenticated, but everybody can see, copy, and run the URL from your JavaScript.
3. Even if you fix #1 and your `ReplyCreate()` action gets called, it's expecting 2 parameters, but you're only sending one (`aidx`). The other parameter (`replyArticles`) will be always `null`.
4. Your code is vulnerable to CSRF attack.

To fix #1, you can add the parameter to your form instead of JavaScript, and change your button's type to `submit`:

```
<form id="formdata"
 action="@Url.Action("Detail", "Board", null, new { aidx = Model.Article.ArticleIDX })"
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="dividewhite2"></div>
    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-lgr-str">답글달기</button></p>
</form>
```

Or you can use a hidden field.

To fix #2, move the check outside the form and delete your JavaScript:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    <form id="formdata"
     action="@Url.Action("Detail", "Board", null, new { aidx = Model.Article.ArticleIDX })"
     method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="dividewhite2"></div>
        <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-lgr-str">답글달기</button></p>
    </form>
}
```

To fix #3, you'll have to add the `replyArticles` parameter to your form or as a hidden field.

To fix #4, you'll need to add the forgery check to your form and your action.

Comment: I uploaded my original code again. Are you still vulnerable and need to change the type of button? I want to add a controller to write. I'm going to add a feature to the answer. So I want to pass parameters to the controller.

Comment: Yes, you're still vulnerable and you need to change the type of the button.

Comment: The view we are currently viewing is a detail view. Can I change the type of button without saving it?

Comment: I see. Well, then why do you need a form if it's only for viewing? In that case, ignore my answer. Just delete the form, your don't need it. And you can convert the button to links, so you don't need JavaScript. Or you can keep the buttons if you really want.

Comment: I am creating the reply function of the bulletin board. So, if you press the button, you have to go to the window where you can write your reply. So you did not set the button type to submit. How do I take data from the detail view to the controller?

Comment: You can use links for that, I think they're better than buttons. But if you prefer buttons, then the way you did it is good. What is the problem you're having?